# Flutter: get data from json

Tags: json, flutter, dart

When I print out print(response.body), I am a getting a json data like this:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
  "etag": "BaEhOMCS17JNvG29RdTWOMEWXcM",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "jUDRGv06hm-CRn0BiOCPfDAB_ww",
      "id": "zVGjcT-w2R0",
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2021-02-20T16:00:32Z",
        "channelId": "UCCkcCJBEKZ0sLKVYxlN1fkw",
        "title": "SHES GONE | Little Nightmares 2 Gameplay Walkthrough Part 5 THE END",
        "description": "The Scariest of The Littlest of Nightmares\nor just a scary little game \nThis Is The Ending Of Little Nightmares 2",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/zVGjcT-w2R0/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/zVGjcT-w2R0/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/zVGjcT-w2R0/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 4<…>
```

From this json object, how can I get the title from this json data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is not complete, even so I'm supposing the starting data type is `Map<String, dynamic>`, then this snippet should work:

```
var data = {"kind": "...", "etag": "...", "items": [...]};
var title = (((data['items'] as List).first as Map)['snippet'] as Map)['title'];
```

Comment: then: `var data = myData['flutter'];` and run my code above....

Comment: @Uni is right, your data should be firstly parsed with `jsonDecode`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is called `json deserialization / json decoding`. You need to decode the json string into a `Map<String,dynamic>`:

```
final parsed = jsonDecode(response.body);
```

Now that we have the values in a `Map<String,dynamic>`. You could loop through your `item` array and get the `title's` value:

```
for (int i = 0; i < parsed["items"].length; i++) {
  print(parsed["items"][i]["snippet"]["title"]);
}
```

Here is a the flutter documentation about how to deserialize json: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing

Comment: I am getting this error:  Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'cast' with matching arguments.

Comment: @DarylWong You can remove the `.cast()`. I updated my answer

Comment: getting a null value

Comment: @DarylWong My bad, I didn't see the snippet part of your json. I've updated my answer.